# Adb Timeout after one day with my device

Tags: android, adb

I am beginner in android.My problem is I had connect my mobile device with adb through adb tcpip 5555 and adb connect  command in the cmd (first time via cable) and it successfully work and work wireless in android studio but on the next day when I am reconnecting with my device it does not work until I repeat the process again that is for the first time do all the process via cable and make connection.

So My Question is, Is there is any solution available that adb connection require only one time setting and after that it work until I dissconnet manually, Also I want the solution without rooting the android phone

Comment: I think People should answer me or correct my question rather than dislike

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow this step first time at least

1)adb tcpip 5555

2)adb connect 192.168.0.101:5555

after that badly your device disconnect then you need to do above step again but one thing is there first hit this command and then follow above two step

1.adb kill-server

2.abb start-server

By the way it does not required root phone.

Comment: I think You didn't understand my Question/Problem.The Command which you gave is worked but after sometime or most probably when the PC is shut down and restart for example the day after then I have to reprocess the above things that is again connecting with the wire to connect adb with the device.

Comment: Yes I understand your question it is not possible as per my knowledge.